# Spring Webservice Client - Problems creating

Tags: web-services, spring, jaxb2

I am new to Spring, so my apologies if this seems obvious. I am trying to create a JUnit test case that calls my webservice. I think I finally got the gist of wat I am suppose to do, but keep getting errors. I have a basic test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)<br>
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/test.xml"})
public class Tester {
private WebServiceTemplate service;
@Test
public void testEntityWS(){
    EntityDetailsRequest request = new ObjectFactory().createEntityDetailsRequest();
    EntityDetailsRequest.CallerReference callerReference = new EntityDetailsRequest.CallerReference();
    callerReference.setAuthenticationToken("ASD345F8F9");
    callerReference.setRequestingEntity(123456l);
    request.setCallerReference(callerReference);
    request.setSchemaVersion(new Float(1.0));
    request.setLegalReferenceNumberType("123456");

    EntityDetailsResponse response = (EntityDetailsResponse) service.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    System.out.println("DONE");
    System.out.println(response.getEntityNumber());
}
```

}

This is my Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="Jaxb2.marshaller" contextPath="za.co.discovery.finance.card.xml"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" id="entityService">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:7001/entities/services/entityWebservice"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="Jaxb2.marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="Jaxb2.marshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean class="za.co.discovery.services.TestEntitiesWS" id="testEntitiesWS">
    <property name="service" ref="entityService"/>
</bean>
```

First of all - is this correct? Is this all I have to do to call the webservice (exposed by another party). Then - I am getting the error below. It is a null pointer exception on the service attribute. So looks like the config file never injects into the service? Is this possible? Any ideas why this happens? (I use to get JaxB exceptions - so I know it went to the config file).

PS: This is the full stack trace if anyone is interested:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Tester.testEntityWS(Tester.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: This is Line 34:                               EntityDetailsResponse response = (EntityDetailsResponse) service.marshalSendAndReceive(request);                          The "service" object is null. So it looks to me like "service" is not being initialied by the Spring config. I don't know why - did I do something wrong when I configured?

Comment: Okay - so I think I figured it out. I put '@Autowired' above the "service" attribute and tadaa. It works.So my question is: Is it alwas necessary to put this annotation in? And while on that topic...is it necessary to put the '@ContextConfiguration' annotation. Can't I set this up in my project so java/Spring knows where to look?